# UnexpectedAlertPresentException while handling alerts in chrome using selenium

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

ChromeDriver Version = 2.24/2.2
Chrome Browser Version = 52
Selenium is  = 2.53.6
Python = 2.7

My Code is like

```
browser.find_element_by_id("save").click()
browser.switch_to_alert().accept()
```

As suggested across different forums and posts I tried putting `sleep`, `try` `catch` blocks, `WebDriverWait` for alert to present but none of them helped.

Also I noticed my code is not even going to line `browser.switch_to_alert().accept()`, `click()` operation itself was throwing error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Are you sure you want to save changes?}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is an alert and not a regular pop-up?

Comment: Yes it is an alert

Comment: What browser are you using?? And what is your selenium version??

Comment: It is the first thing mentioned in my question.